# JUnit base test auto setUp

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'd like to write a `BaseTest` class that simply provides a "universal `setUp()` method" for all extending subclasses:

```
public class BaseTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("setUp() was called!");

        // Doesn't really matter what this is doing...
        EnvironmentConfigurator.configureEnvForTesting();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public class WidgetTest extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        fail();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        fail();
    }
}
```

So ideally, every time a subclass method annotated by `@Test` is executed, JUnit would first call the `BaseTest#setUp()` method, which does whatever (doesn't really matter). Perhaps its resetting some mock states to an initial value so that each test can start on a "clean slate", etc. Again, doesn't really matter.

Unfortunately when I run this code, I only see `setUp() was called!` printing to the screen **once**, so clearly `BaseTest` isn't "wrapping" my `@Test` methods the way I want. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just ran this and both test methods are called and both times setUp is called.

If you have a `@Before` annotated method in the derived class as well then you will need to name the base class setup method to something different e.g. setUpBase() because if the method names are the same only the `@Before` annotated method in the derived class is called as it would be overriding the method in the base class.

Comment: Thanks @Bedwyr Humphreys (+1) - I changed my `fail()` statements to semi-colons (to force the test methods to pass) and yes, the parent `setUp()` method was called twice. So there must be something about using this setup combined with failing test cases that causes the `setUp()` method to only be called once. Thanks again.

Comment: I ran it with the fail() (in Eclipse) and it was still called twice

Comment: Strange... well doesn't matter, removing the `fail()`s works so I'm good to go. Thanks again.

Comment: Hehe. I am so stupid :) I also used the same method name and I was wondering why it does not get called. Thanks. +1